# Having issues with using COM Autofilter in AHK language

Tags: excel, autohotkey, autofilter

I'm able to apply the Autofilter criteria but the filtered rows are not visible. However, if I go to advanced filter, and click Ok on the already applied filter, then the results appear. I don't know what's happening, here is the code.

```
    try xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
catch e
{
xl := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
}

wb_YTD := xl.Workbooks.Open(A_Desktop "\R&B YTD.xlsx")

if (WinExist("BnR Weekly Counts"))
wb_bnr :=  xl.Workbooks.Item("BnR Weekly Counts")
else
wb_bnr := xl.Workbooks.Open(A_Desktop "\BnR Weekly Counts.xlsx")

wb_YTD.Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Autofilter
FormatTime, current_month, YYYYMMDDHH24MISS, M

criteria1 := "> " current_month "/9/" A_Year
criteria2 := "< " current_month "/11/" A_Year

wb_YTD.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1").AutoFilter(Field := 3,Criteria1 := criteria1, Operator := 1, Criteria2 := criteria2)
```

Here, Column 3 contains the dates that I want to filter, Criteria1 is > 2/9/2020 and Criteria 2 is < 2/11/2020

Thanks!

Comment: This does not look like VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caught the error, the extra 'space' in the criteria "> " was causing this error

Working filter code:

```
FormatTime, current_month, YYYYMMDDHH24MISS, M ; To store the month count without extra 0
start_date := ">=" current_month "/9/" A_Year
end_date := "<=" current_month "/15/" A_Year

wb_YTD.Sheets(1).Range("A1:F10000").AutoFilter(Field := 3,Criteria1 := start_date, Operator := 1, Criteria2 := end_date)
```